# c++ HMENU display messagebox

Tags: c++

hey i am trying to create a meny in notepad.exe

i already created it but i want display a message box after click on Reload

i tried

```
    #define MSG         (WM_APP + 101)
    HWND hWnd = FindWindow(NULL,TEXT("untitled - Notepad"));
    HMENU hCurrent = GetMenu(hWnd);
    HMENU hNew     = CreateMenu();
    AppendMenu(hCurrent, MF_STRING | MF_POPUP, (unsigned int)hNew, TEXT("TheDragoN"));
    AppendMenu(hNew, MF_STRING, MSG, TEXT("Reload"));
    AppendMenu(hNew, MF_STRING, 200, TEXT("Credits"));
    DrawMenuBar(hWnd); 
WPARAM wParam;
               switch(LOWORD(wParam))
               {
                    case MSG:
                        MessageBox(hWnd, L"TSSAA", L"MessSDSageBox",MB_OK);
                        break;
               }
```

but it didnt display the message box

Comment: This cannot work without using SetWindowsHookEx().

Answer (score 0):

You declare `WPARAM wParam;` without any initialisation and immediatelly check what's in lo word, result is unspecified as `wParam` will contain some default rubbish value.

Comment: i am trying to find it since 3 hours, but i couldnt

Comment: @MetayJack, what are you trying to find?

Comment: solution to display this message :D

Comment: I doesn't look like you are though. You are declaring `WPARAM wParam;` and expect it to be initialised by magic. This simply isn't going to happen. What you need to do is intercept `WM_COMMAND` message generated by the menu. To do that in external application you need to use a hook, see `SetWindowsHookEx` for details